# Custom fonts on my first ViewController works after turning back from another view

Tags: swift, fonts, custom-font

I used custom fonts alot ! and I tried some different type of codes...

But on this Special case I can't help myself.

I tried many codes but for example this one:

```
let navbarFont = UIFont(name: "santa", size: 15) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: navbarFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()]
```

It Works but not at first ! If I navigate through another view and come back, then it will show up.

I tried to put the code on "viewWillAppear" too. but the result was the same...

Although there is nothing wrong with this code on other ViewControllers...

Comment: try putting this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of appdelegate class

Comment: OH MY GOD !  Works Perfect ! Thank You ! I can Accept it as aswer if you answer it...

Comment: just post as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of appdelegate class